# Reverting to local code after a git pull origin master

Tags: git

Is there a way to get the local version back!? The local version is required but has been overwritten. The version we want is not in the git repository. Is there a way to get the local version back that does not appear in our branch?

The original files were changed manually - that is without any tracking. So now, fear these are totally lost. The file we want to recover was overwritten by the pull origin master and the manually edited version didn't exist anywhere but the local machine.

The previous version was never checked in - but does git somehow preserve any information about the file that it overwrites, even though that file has never been checked-in?

Comment: The local version was never in git?

Comment: What is 'local code'? A pull does not overwrite local non-committed changes. You can always go back to a specific commit using `git checkout COMMIT_ID`

Comment: @MichaelHoff Local code is non checkedin code - done manually.

Comment: Please be more descriptive. It is "not checked in" - "done manually". Does that mean the file is not under version control (a.k.a. untracked)? It would help if you could into explain what your situation was, what you then did *exactly*, what the current situation is like and what is actually desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not commit the "changes" at any time, then **no**, you can not get them back using git.

You may get them back if the system is backed-up in any other way, but git doesn't provide any way to get back a non-commited file modification.

Comment: one more solution will help you restore your system to previous day, It may help you as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Here one solution is before the pull from the `master`  Revert the `local` code

**git stash**
or after git pull the code If you are using ***Android Studio Tool*** maintain `local` history you can Easy to Revert Otherwise your code is merged on your `local` branch you can't do revert

Comment: This might be useful for the future. But I don't see how this could be used to get back to the unchecked in code.

Comment: Hello,`@Navonod` one solution for this `git` `reset --hard `